# Prevent transloadit-rails overlay and progres bar to show when no file is attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transloadit

In a form where it's optional to attach an image
When there is no image attached and the user submits the form
Then transloadit overlay and progress bar is shown
Then the submission form hangs when it reaches 100%

I want to prevent overlay and progress bar from showing when there is no file to upload

Comment: Is `progressZeroFiles` `true`? For a better answer, maybe share more code. If that's a problem here, try the official support channel

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to add the `processZeroFiles: false` parameter to the `jquerify` function. Like this:

```
<%= transloadit_jquerify :upload, :wait => true, processZeroFiles: false %>
```

I then had to ensure the `params[:transloadit]` parameter existed in my controller before trying to access it since it non longer hits transloadit every time I update or create an instance of my model object.

**Comment Typo**

Notice that the parameter is actually `processZeroFiles` and not `progressZeroFiles` as mentioned in the comment on the question by @kvz.